# Cisco VPN not connecting to internet

Tags: networking, vpn, 20.04, openvpn, cisco

I am trying to connect to my office vpn. When I try to connect with Cisco Anyconnect Client it does connect but it restricts only the private sites of office.

Is there some way I could open other global sites while being connected to this VPN. I saw the option of split tunneling but the problem I am facing with that is

When I try creating VPN connection in Network Connections options, there it is not able to connect to the office private sites even though it mentions being connected.

Please forgive if it still not understandable, I tried asking with as much info I have about networking.

Comment: @Nmath Yes contacted them, they mentioned to add the wpad auto proxy configuration. Now it works for both. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set the Automatic Proxy Configuration (WPAD).
- Automatic configuration script http://wpad/wpad.dat added to LAN Connection Settings.

Under Network, click Settings...
Automatic proxy configuration URL: Click the radio button.
Enter http://wpad/wpad.dat. and Save